# Unable to load custom JS file in Django admin home

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce

I am trying to add Custom css and js in my django admin. But CSS is working but js is not working. I have checked my code. I don't think there is any error in my code.

my `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Blog

# Register your models here.


class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ('css/main.css',)

        }
        JS = ('js/blog.js',)
admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

my `blog.js`

```
console.log("This is blog.js");
let sc = document.createElement('script')
sc.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js')


document.head.appendChild(sc);



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log("This is blog.js");
    let sc = document.createElement('script')
    sc.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js')


    document.head.appendChild(sc);
    sc.onload = ()=>{
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#id_content'
        });
    }


});
```

In the first line of js I have written a code `console.log("This is blog.js");`. But while inspecting the page I didn't see "This is blog.js" in console. It means my js is not loading in Django admin.
Please look into this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `js` is uppercase in class `Media`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the static file management done properly?

- Is there a `STATIC_URL` and a `STATIC_ROOT` defined in your
  settings.py file
- Also, have you properly set up the server to deliver the static files?
- Finally, if you have done everything, check whether changes happen when you make changes in the original file rather than one created after running the command `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, my friend, it works. Took me a long time to figure this out. I was also stuck on the same .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    let sc = document.createElement('script')
    sc.setAttribute('src','https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js');  
    document.head.appendChild(sc);
    sc.onload = ()=>{
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#id_content'
        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.